# I heard so many translation for "casino royale" Bond movie

Tags: meaning, translation

is the name "Casino Royale" correct? or should it probably better "Royale Casino"?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. The name of the movie **is** _Casino Royale_; what translations are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, because it is in French.

> **[Royale-les-Eaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royale-les-Eaux)** is a fictional town in Northern France. It features in the James Bond novels of Ian Fleming and others,
>   particularly *Casino Royale* and *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*.

---

> ***[Casino Royale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(novel))*** is the first novel by the British author Ian Fleming. Published in 1953, it is the first James Bond book, and it
>   paved the way for a further eleven novels and two short story
>   collections by Fleming, followed by numerous continuation Bond novels
>   by other authors.
>
> The story concerns the British secret agent James Bond, gambling at
>   the casino in Royale-les-Eaux to bankrupt Le Chiffre, the treasurer of
>   a French union and a member of the Russian secret service.

---

> In general, and unlike English, French adjectives are placed after the
>   noun they describe. Here are a few adjectives that illustrate this
>   difference with English.
>
> - **une maison blanche** (a white house)
> - **un visage intéressant** (an interesting face)
> - **des gâteaux délicieux** (delicious cakes)
>
> https://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-place-of-french-adjectives-correctly/

As a general [rule](https://www.proz.com/forum/translation_theory_and_practice/160901-translation_of_company_names.html), proper names of companies and business are not translated (certainly not from French - exceptions may exist for names in non-Latin alphabets).

---

Note that in the [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(2006_film)) adaptation, the casino is placed in Montenegro.

Comment: The before-or-after question is quite complex: [Quelle différence y a-t-il entre un grand homme et un homme grand ?](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2016/12/20/37003-20161220ARTFIG00006-quelle-difference-y-a-t-il-entre-un-grand-homme-et-un-homme-grand.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could view it as an abbreviated form of "The Casino called Royale."

Answer (score -2):

English does not absolutely require that the adjective precede the noun, but usually when the order is reversed, there is a specific reason, typically either because the phrase is from a poem or ceremonial text ("the choir invisible", "the body politic") or because the phrase has been imported intact from another language, such as French, where that's the preferred order.

"Royale" is an interest case.  We imported the French word as "royal" and that is used literally, meaning associated with the ruling house of a country.  When the French spelling is used (of the feminine singular), it means, basically, "fancy" or "impressive" and trails the noun in the French fashion: "battle royale", "casino royale".

Comment: It would be Casino Royal if _Royal_ was being used as an adjective.